# Run a command in the middle of a script as root

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need that in the middle of a script in bash a line be executed as root, I have this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
EOF

if [[ $x = true ]] || [[ $y= "On" ]]; then
echo -e "0 8    * * *   root " >> /etc/crontab
```

I need the echo written in the crontab by the root user, who has a password.
Currently it does not write as it is executed by the ubuntu user.
Thank you.

Comment: I do not mind putting the password in the script

Comment: How about being a `sudo` user with `NOPASS`

Comment: Use `sudo` or `expect`.

Answer (score 3):

I propose this:

```
echo -e "0 8    * * *   root " | sudo tee -a /etc/crontab
```

When your script encounters the `sudo` for the `tee`, it will ask for your password or, if you already gave your password for sudo just recently, it will just execute the task.  (Of course, if this user doesn't need to type a password for `sudo`, it will never ask for it.)

Using `tee -a` instead of shell redirection works around the fact that redirections are performed by the current shell, so adding `sudo` to the command will not affect the redirect (and then it will fail due to missing permissions).